# ms sql call stored procedure with date time parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, clrstoredprocedure

how do one call a stored procedure that has date input .

```
spName getDate()
```

does not work.

the question is about calling within ms sql managment studio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL Server 2008

```
declare @d date = getdate() /*Or datetime looking at the title*/
exec spName @d
```

Earlier Versions

```
declare @d datetime
set @d = getdate()
exec spName @d
```

Comment: I've known for more than a decade that SQL Server procedures can't take functions as parameters, but I still try to do this every now and again. Because it _should_ work, damn it :)